# Cloudfoundry buildpack .net version error

Tags: .net-core, version, cloud-foundry, buildpack

When I deploy my .net core 2.1.0 project, I get the following error:

```
-----> Installing dotnet-framework 2.0.3
       **ERROR** DEPENDENCY MISSING IN MANIFEST:

Version 2.0.3 of dependency dotnet-framework is not supported by this buildpack.
The versions of dotnet-framework supported in this buildpack are:
    - 1.0.5
    - 1.0.10
    - 1.0.11
    - 1.1.2
    - 1.1.7
    - 1.1.8
    - 2.0.0
    - 2.0.7
    - 2.1.0
```

All solutions in my project is targeting the .net core framework 2.1.0, so I don't understand why this is.
I have dependencies in my project, and some of the them, like NETStandard.Library and Microsoft.NETCore.DotNetAppHost, are version 2.0.3, but does that really matter? (Also I don't think a version higher than 2.0.3 exist of NetStandard.Library.)

The project runs fine on my local machine, and ran fine on the host before we upgraded the buildpack and target .net framework, as well as various dependencies through NuGet.

Here is the full log:
https://1drv.ms/t/s!Ar81AKlFywcPhapTJdjZEnrcGrZS4A

Comment: Do you have a sample project that you could link to which replicates the error?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to pin the RuntimeFrameworkVersion to a specific one:

```
<RuntimeFrameworkVersion>2.0.7</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>
```